# Get parameter from another page in JSP

Tags: jsp

I have the first page of so-called **admin.jsp** which consists of the following:

```
      <c:if test="${param.action == 'testA'}">
              <jsp:include page="testA.jsp" />
      </c:if>
```

within **testA.jsp**, it consists of the following:

```
      <%@include file="testB.jsp" %>
      <%@include file="testC.jsp" %>
```

There're plenty of html codes reside in **testC.jsp** e.g :

```
      <input type="hidden" id="checkA" value="check1">
      <input type="hidden" id="checkB" value="check2">
```

which I would like to use it in **testB.jsp**. I did try to use request.getParameter("checkA") or request.getParameter("checkB") but it returned null. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why do you think that testB.jsp should have a request parameter called checkA, just because it happens to be included before another JSP which has a hidden field call checkA? A request parameter is a parameter sent with a reqiest. It's not some reference to a hidden field included later in the same request processing.

Comment: @JBNizet: I want to use string query which normally done on testC.jsp. So, i need to grab its parameter to be used later on testB.jsp. Anyway, I added value on hidden field above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<portlet:defineObjects />
<%= renderRequest.getAttribute("add") %><br>
```